# Download a file via a POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an API endpoint that dynamically generates an image based on some pass data. I would like to call the API and download the response into a file. What's the best way to accomplish this in Python?

The request looks like this in cURL:

```
curl https://localhost:4000/bananas/12345.png \
  -O \
  -X POST \
  -d '[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `requests` package instead of executing `curl` or other processes:

```
import requests

response = requests.post('https://localhost:4000/bananas/12345.png', data = '[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]')
data = response.content
```

`data` contains the downloaded content after that, which you can store to disk for instance:

```
with open(path, 'wb') as s:
    s.write(data)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Python newbie here. Would `data` contain the binary content of the file, or does Python assume a default encoding? Also, how would I write the response content to a file?

Comment: @LandonSchropp Most of these questions, including your original, could've been answered with a little google searching... so I recommend you get on that...

Comment: Yes, it will be a byte array. I've added an example how to save to disk.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @cs95 oddly enough google returns this page as a result when searching. I think a lot of people use stackoverflow as a first choice in their results, and I would imagine that stackoverflow benefits from the traffic.

Answer (score -3):

I'd prefer `subprocess` over `os.system` any day, so here's the equivalent:

```
import subprocess

_CURL_POST = "curl https://localhost:4000/bananas\
/12345.png \
-O \
-X POST \
-d '[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]'
"

subprocess.call(_CURL_POST)
```

Comment: Python has libs for doing URL requests. Executing subprocesses is a very bad solution.

Comment: `Please add your suggestions as new answer :)` This was bad advice, you shouldn't have taken it. There's no better way to do this than using a standard library for the task, rather than making subprocess calls.